# How to aggregate the values of a DataFrame (and output a numpy array quickly)?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Given the following DataFrame in pandas:

```
user    item     rating
1       3        2
1       4        5
2       1        5
3       5        1
3       1        3
4       4        4
4       1        1
....
```

I'd like to transfer it to a numpy array, with the user column as y-axis and item column as x-axis, like this:

```
    1   2   3    4    5 
1   nan nan 2    5    nan
2   5   nan nan  nan  nan
3   3   nan nan  nan  1
4   1   nan nan  4    nan
```

How can I use the `apply` function to do it quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it quickly , make it with numpy tools:

```
def pivotarray(df):
    users,i= np.unique(df['user'],return_inverse=True)
    item,j= np.unique(df['item'],return_inverse=True)
    a=zeros((len(users),len(item)),int)
    a[i,j]=df['rating']
    return a
```

Then (you can fill a with NaN before if requisite) :

```
In [464]: pivotarray(df)
Out[464]: 
array([[0, 2, 5, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 4, 0]])
```

column 2 is not there because there is no item 2.

Gain is significative :

```
In [465]: %timeit pivotarray(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 417 µs per loop

In [466]: %timeit df.pivot(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
100 loops, best of 3: 6.38 ms per loop

In [467]: %timeit df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop
```

*EDIT*

for including missing items, a possible hack:

```
def pivotarraywithallitems(df):
    users,i= np.unique(df['user'],return_inverse=True)
    item,j= np.unique(df['item'],return_inverse=True)
    miss= (~in1d(arange(1,6),item)).cumsum()
    j+=miss[j]
    a=zeros((len(users),len(item)+miss[-1]),float)*NaN
    a[i,j]=df['rating']
    return a
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a pivot table:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
       1   3   4   5
user                
1    NaN   2   5 NaN
2      5 NaN NaN NaN
3      3 NaN NaN   1
4      1 NaN   4 NaN
```

Note that totally `NaN` columns are present; you can reindex to include them if needed:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
      .reindex_axis([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], axis=1)

item   1   2   3   4   5
user                    
1    NaN NaN   2   5 NaN
2      5 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3      3 NaN NaN NaN   1
4      1 NaN NaN   4 NaN
```

To put these values into a NumPy array, access the `.values` attribute:

```
_.values # _ is the last returned value in the repr
```

Comment: Is better use `pivot_table` as `pivot`?

Comment: <offtopic> I have exactly the same question - what is faster for such a simple case?</offtopic>

Comment: `pivot_table` is slower than `pivot` (mainly because it applies an aggfunc to the data values and supports hierarchical indexing). So if your priority is performance you should probably use the latter. If you want to control how values are aggregated (mean, sum, etc.), then `pivot_table`  is the way to go. For the very simple case in the question, @jezrael's suggestion of `pivot` seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html):

```
print df.pivot(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
item   1   3   4   5
user                
1    NaN   2   5 NaN
2      5 NaN NaN NaN
3      3 NaN NaN   1
4      1 NaN   4 NaN
```

Then you need add missing columns - find `min` and `max` values, create range for parameter label in [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print df['item'].min()
1

print df['item'].max()
5

rng = range(df['item'].min(), df['item'].max() + 1)
print rng
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print df.pivot(index='user',columns='item',values='rating').reindex_axis(labels=rng, axis=1)
item   1   2   3   4   5
user                    
1    NaN NaN   2   5 NaN
2      5 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3      3 NaN NaN NaN   1
4      1 NaN NaN   4 NaN
```

Last use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for generating `numpy array`:

```
print df.pivot(index='user', columns='item', values='rating')
        .reindex_axis(labels=rng, axis=1)
        .values

[[ nan  nan   2.   5.  nan]
 [  5.  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [  3.  nan  nan  nan   1.]
 [  1.  nan  nan   4.  nan]]
```

Comment: thanks for you reply first. I got `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` error. I did not add missing columns as it was not necessary. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: It is very common error and solution is `pivot_table` with `aggfunc`. Dont forget ' default `aggfunc` is `np.mean`